# javap doesn't show the type of the Collection

Tags: java

```
public static java.util.List getFoo(java.lang.String)
```

The above method returns a `List<String>`, but the `javap` command returns the above (it doesn't show that the `List` is of type `String`). Is there a way to show the real type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type is a lie :) Well seriously, that's just compile time information. The entries of the list are casted to Strings when fetched from the collection, the list itself in bytecode format acts as any standard plain old List.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 1):

The runtime type of a parameterized object is always erased, so no.  See [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in the [Generics Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) of the [Learning the Java Language Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the signature of the function

```
public static java.util.List<String> getFoo(java.lang.String).
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. agree with You and Mikko.

Answer (score 0):

javap is blind to parameterized type String in this case.

I did test with an analogous example. With Linux command *hexdump*, the parameterized type is showed.